# Binomial theorem - number of terms in expansion

Tags: binomial-theorem, regular-expressions

Question:
Find the number of terms, after simplifying, in $$(x + y + \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y})^{16}$$

I was unable to find any approach to this question. Fully expanding the expression isn't a viable solution. A hint to start the problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$$x+y+\frac1x+\frac1y=\frac{(x+y)(1+xy)}{xy}$$

Now, $(a+b)^n$ has $n+1$ terms for integer $n\ge0$

Comment: Didn't you miss some exponents ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, I meant the current version. Thanks for your observation

Comment: Well, that has certainly made it easier. Let me try it now.

Comment: Well after distributing the exponents, you get 17 terms from each bracket from the numerator. As they are being multiplied together, we will get 17*17 total terms. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it is ! Cheers

Comment: Well that was an easy question then. Didn't get the hint to simplify it before applying binomial theorem.

Comment: @Gummybears. When you see problems like this one, be sure that there is a trick. Consider you are lucky with the power $16$; they could have asked that question with power $12345$ !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I see. Well it really doesn't matter what the power is. Even with 16, its impractical to go about expanding the expression, isn't it?

Comment: I agree ! This is why the hint provided by lab bhattacharjee is important.